# getNextIteration

Tags: rally

Using API 2.0, I am working on a super kanban board, and when rendering the card I want a button that will move the story to the next sprint.

I started with adding the iteration combo, but that is overkill.  I can add the button and the code, but is there a way to get the next iteration?

I dont see anything out there, thought I would ask here before I started coding.

The kanban board is iteration specific, so i could move up a sprint or two and still want to push it forward, so figure I have to grab the current iteration and somehow get the next one...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for iterations where the start date is after today, ordered by start date.  That should give you the next iteration in records[0]...

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
    model: 'Iteration',
    fetch: ['Name', 'StartDate', 'EndDate'],
    autoLoad: true,
    sorters: [
        {
            property: 'StartDate'
            direction: 'ASC'
        }
    ],
    filters: [
        {
            property: 'StartDate',
            operator: '>',
            value: Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(new Date()) 
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records) {
            var nextIteration = records[0];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, this looks close.  To actually get the next iteration, I would pull the start date of the **stories** current iteration.  I think I can manage that :).  I will see how it goes, thanks for the answer !